# should I use const if passed object will not be modified now, but can be modified later

Tags: c++

I am writing a game in which each data object is displayed by a ControlView. When a ControlView is set to display the data object, it should not change it. I want to use const to enforce this convention . However, in response to user interaction with the ControlView later, the data may be modified. So a non-const pointer needs to be stored. I am wondering if this is accepted and correct usage of const_cast?. skeletal code below

```
class Data
{
  int m_int;
  public:
    void add(int i)  { m_int += i ; };
 };

class ControlView
{
 Data* m_data;
 public:
 void set_data(const Data* d)  //this call should not change d 
        { 
            m_data=const_cast<Data*>(d); //cast needed to compile
        }; 

        void manipulate_data(int x)
        { 
            m_data->add(x);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, no, don't use `const`. If you do, you're letting anyone pass a `const` as a parameter, and may end up running into undefined behavior afterwards:

```
 const Data d;
 ControlView c;
 c.setData(&d);    //legal, because setData takes a const as parameter
 c.manipulateData(0);  //undefined behavior, modifying an originally const object
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I guess to enforce the "contract" that the method should not change the passed Data in that call, I can convert it to const before working with it:
      void set_data(Data* in_d)  
   { 
    const Data* d=in_d; // passed data will not be changed  in this call
    //....work with d 
    m_data=in_d;     };

Comment: @user1057165 I'd stay away from const casts alltogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever want to modify the object, do not make it `const`. Modifying a `const` object, e.g. through `const_cast`, is undefined behavior.

So don't use `const` for `m_data`, however there are a couple of other `const`s you can use in your code:

- You can protect function arguments with `const`. This is usually not very meaningful since you typically don't care about the pointer, but rather the object it points to. But it can help you avoid bugs like accidentally repointing `d` in your code:

```c
void set_data(Data * const d); // const pointer to (non-const) Data
// this means the function can not change d (the pointer), but it can
// change the object that d points to.
```

- You can make non-modifying functions `const`. This declares that the function will not change the object in any way (except if there are `mutable` members). The compiler will error if you attempt to modify any member in such a function. These functions are also the only ones you can call on a `const` object.

```c
Data * get_data() const; // this function doesn't change anything
```

Note that if you have `mutable` members, they **can** be changed from const functions, but this should not be abused. This is meant for internal things like mutexes or caching.

Also note that references are always `const` - they can not be reassigned to point to another object. The object they reference can be const or non-const.

Final tip: Read the declarations right-to-left:

```c
Data       *       d;   // pointer to Data (both can be changed)
Data       * const d;   // const pointer to Data (data can be changed)
Data const *       d;   // pointer to const Data (pointer can be changed)
Data const * const d;   // const pointer to const Data (neither can be changed)

Data         &       d;   // reference to non-const Data
//Data       & const d;   // invalid - all references are const
Data const   &       d;   // reference to const Data
//Data const & const d;   // invalid - all references are const
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to realise what `const data *d` means. It means that the pointer `d` can be altered, but the pointer `d` points to objects of type `Data` that are `const` i.e. immutable.

What you should have is

```
void set_data(Data * const d)  //this call should not change d 
{ 
    m_data=d;
};
```

The bit of code `Data  * const d` means that the pointer d cannot be altered by the method, but d points to objects that can be altered.

My philosophy is that when you are using casts you are maybe doing something wrong. Try to avoid them.

Comment: I think he already knows this. But you do know that `const` for a non-reference value is kinda redundant, no? Even if you don't make the actual pointer `const` and you modify it, the change is not visible outside the function, right? It's like passing an `int` by `const` & by value - doesn't really accomplish anything.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - It is just good practice. Also it does give the compiler an extra opportunity for optimisation. In addition for larger function is does offer some protection for you as a coder from not making silly mistakes.

Comment: I think the `const` value is just there for semantic purposes. There's no mistakes you as a programmer could make in the absence of `const` applied to a value since it's a value. There's also no aditional opportunity for optimization (but if you can prove there are, that'd be awesome). Again, we're talking here about pass by value, not reference - that would be completely different.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - 1. It prevents you from modifying the value throughout the function inadvertently. e.g. calling other functions. 2. The compiler can optimize it by not having to make a copy of the pointer in some occasions.

Comment: I don't follow either point. Even if you do modify the value, it doesn't matter because it was passed by value, so the change won't hold outside the function, right? As for 2. can you provide some code + profiling?

Comment: 1. If you modify the value and you use it later on in that method assuming that it points to the original value you have introduced a bug. Using `const` prevents you making this mistake. 2. Before calling a function the compiler puts the parameters on the stack. The optimizer could rearrange the order so that it does not have to put one or more of the parameters on the stack thus avoiding a copy. This can be quite a saving if the method is called in a loop.

Comment: "If you modify the value and you use it later on in that method assuming that it points to the original value you have introduced a bug." - but doesn't that mean you need to modify the value, ergo can't make it `const`? The alternative is to make a copy of it, and modify that instead, but then we go back to the reasoning I already had - that the `const` is merely semantic.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - It prevents you making a mistake by modifying it or making a copy. Just extra in the armory from making mistakes. Also gives the compiler a hint for optimisation.